# Can I use BizSpark credit money (Microsoft Azure) for VSO resources?

Tags: azure, bizspark

I have Microsoft BizSpark subscription which gives me credit money. I can spend them for any Microsoft Azure resource (Cloud Service, VM, DB etc). Also I have configured Continuous Integration based on Visual Studio Online. It provides 240 minutes of free build time then I should pay. The question is can I use my credit money for VSO purposes like build time or load tests?

Comment: The credit for each service is siloed within that service, there is no concept of transferring that credit elsewhere.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about Azure subscription billing

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot transfer that credit.

Think of it like this: Is it tracked and billed through the Azure portal? If no, you can't use it.